# Nginx proxy_redirect with relative paths

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am not a big specialist in nginx administration, I am just a developer. I have two backends running in docker. Let me name them

- backend1:8080
- backend2:8081

Also I have Nginx exposing 443 port with letsencrypt certificated installed. My configuration of Nginx is (env variable FQDN is something like example.com)

```
upstream backend1 {
  server backend1:8080;
}

upstream backend2 {
  server backend2:8081;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  
  server_name ${FQDN} www.${FQDN};
  
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/${FQDN}/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/${FQDN}/privkey.pem;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;
  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

  if ($server_port = 80) { set $https_redirect 1; }
  if ($host ~ '^www\.') { set $https_redirect 1; }
  if ($https_redirect = 1) { return 301 https://${FQDN}$request_uri; }
  
  location /path1/ {
    
    proxy_pass http://backend1/;

    proxy_redirect ~^/(.*) $scheme://$http_host/path1/$1;
    
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header X-Forwarded-For;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    add_header       X-Upstream      $upstream_addr;
  }
  
  location /path2/ {
    
    proxy_pass http://backend2/;

    proxy_redirect ~^/(.*) $scheme://$http_host/path2/$1;
    
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    
    proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header Cookie;
    proxy_pass_header X-Forwarded-For;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    add_header       X-Upstream      $upstream_addr;
  }
}
```

I want that if I request `https://exapmle.com/path1/` then Nginx should go to `http://backend1:8080/` and return me response from that server. The problem is that backend1 (as well as backend2) can response with 302 and redirect to some path eg. `/login`. Nginx redirects my browser to `https://exapmle.com/login` but I want it to redirect me to `https://exapmle.com/path1/login`
Could you help me please and point to the error that I made in my configuration. I've reviwed all similar questions in SO and not found any solution. Also I've explored Nginx documentation and also have not found the answer.

I have the line `proxy_redirect ~^/(.*) $scheme://$http_host/path1/$1;` and I suppose it must do the work I want.

BTW I cannot occupy / location (create configuration for the root path) in my Nginx config as it is reserved to another backend server.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first parameter of the `proxy_redirect` statement must match the text string returned in the `Location` header of the 302 response. You should use `curl -I` to identify the exact text of the header.

Comment: You must configure your backend application to generate such URLs. It does not know that you are serving its routes at /path1 (or /path2 or whatever) unless you explicitly told it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Unfortunately these backends are not configurable for proxy usage. They are 3d party applications and do not have any settings for that.

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes I think the same. My 'proxy_redirect' regex is not being hit by returned redirection location. I've checked and found, that backend responses with '/login' in Location header. Nginx merge it with domain name and I get 'https://example.com/login'. Thus Nginx does not match it with '~^/(.*)' and does not add prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of the misspelled X-Forwarded-Headers in your configuration.
It should be `X-Forwarded-*` instead of `X-Forward-*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
location /path1/ {

proxy_pass http://backend1/;

proxy_redirect default;
proxy_redirect / /path1/;
proxy_redirect  http://backend1/ https://exapmle.com/path1/;

proxy_http_version 1.1;

proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
proxy_pass_header Cookie;
proxy_pass_header X-Forwarded-For;

proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
add_header       X-Upstream      $upstream_addr;}
```

that is ok;